# Why there is no animation running

Tags: animation, keyframes

Started learning animation. Im making a box animation how it folds. I set the keyframe rotation location as seen below. But why there is no animation going. Where im going wrong and how it works. Any suggestion or help. Thanks

[image]

Comment: This keyframes work only with object transforms and you are working with mesh itself. You should use armature and animate bones to deform this object.

Comment: @SergeL, I think you should post this as an answer.

Answer (score 4):

This keyframes work only with **object transforms** and you are working with mesh itself (in *Edit mode*).

Using [Armature](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/rigging/armatures/index.html) is the most convenient way to control mesh deformations. In this case you will keyframe location and rotation of armature's bones in order to perform mesh folding.

[image]

Comment: i tried keyframe not getting perfect result. Look as if getting enlarge its not folding . https://imgur.com/a/uMkhcjz

Comment: Shapekey is a whole another story... Look at this answer to get more info about how do they work: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/108763/29200